Bounding box around each paragraph/element of a document
How do I put a bounding box around each paragraph of a document? If a paragraph spans two pages, it is okay for it to be surrounded by separate bounding boxes.
Additionally, I am looking for a header-only solution. In other words, I am looking for a solution which I can simply put in the header of the document, and it will automatically draw bounding boxes around all paragraphs in the document, without having to add any commands around each paragraph of the image.
Before:

After:

\documentclass[aps,pra,twocolumn,10pt,showpacs,preprintnumbers,amsmath,amssymb,floatfix,longbibliography]{revtex4-2}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\title{Sample title Sample title Sample title Sample title}


\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}


Full source code can be downloaded https://arxiv.org/abs/2409.03693.

Welcome to TeX.SX! May I ask why you need this? Do you want to show the boxes or do you want this to be part of the layout? Because if you want to print these boxes you might want to add some padding between the border and the text.

what your image shows is boxes drawn around selected paragraphs. in fact, the page contains several unboxed paragraphs: the section heading, captions, figures etc. there's no way for latex to distinguish these cases, so a fully automatic solution either requires a different format (you don't say whether you're using latex or something else) or code which turns the numbering on and off for every paragraph you want to exempt. that's an indefinitely long list. moreover, we don't know what code produced the before image, so we'd certainly need code, even for a manual solution.

@cfr  Using the par hooks and modifying the @afterheadings macro can do most of what is shown in combination with picture or tikz remember pcture overlay etc....

@yannisl \@afterheadings? but there are numerous other document elements which use paragraphs and we don't know which, if any, would need numbers.

@cfr  some like floats can be detected by booleans such as \@ifundefined{@captype} and marginpars by penalty value, these can be entered in the definition of afterheadings needs more thinking, I am sure, but can be a start.

@JasperHabicht, thanks! My end goal is to find the x and y coordinates of each paragraph (or element) in the rendered page. I am trying to do that through bounding boxes (i.e. subtracting the pixels of before and after images such that only bounding boxes remain, and then calculating their coordinates using image processing.). But if there are inbuilt methods in latex to directly export coordinates, that would be great. After posting this question, I came across "zref-savepos". Does this ring a bell?

@cfr, apologies for the lack of code. I will provide it shortly. But to answer your question about detecting other unboxed paragraphs (i.e. section headings, captions, figures, etc), I am okay with a solution that detects everything (though not ideal). I can try to filter-out non-paragraphs in post-processing.

@cfr, edited the question to add the link to the source code.

then you could just save the positions of the coordinates directly. if you go with something like a tikz solution, you're just using tikz to get the coordinates, having it then use those to draw the boxes and then doing a bunch of processing to get the coordinates back. the coordinates will be in the aux anyhow. but you don't need a drawing package to write them there. the thing to be careful of is which engines you need to support. don't use something specific to pdftex if you need to support luatex or whatever.

please post a minimal example (code) here. questions shouldn't rely on external links so they remain useful to others. but the new properties stuff in the kernel can do what you need, I think.

@cfr, added minimal example code.

@cfr, would you mind elaborating on the tikz solution. Which command can I used to export coordinates of non graphical elements?

if you insist on tikz, you could use tikznodes. presumably for vertical positions since the horizontal you can calculate from the basic page layout, I suppose.
